# Postgres order by change

Tags: javascript, sql, reactjs, postgresql, axios

I am trying to change the order by ID in my Postgres questions database.

It is ordered randomly for some reason, but I want it to be ordered by ID ASC.

I am very new to postgres so I don't know what I am doing..,

I just want the result of this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM public.questions
ORDER BY id ASC
```

but I don't know how to update my database with its order that shows the query output. It doesn't let me save it, I know im doing something wrong.
How do I achieve it?

This is the current order, id goes like 1,2 then 4

[image: THIS IS THE CURRENT ORDER, ID GOES LIKE 1,2 THEN 4]

I want it to look like this in perfect order by id 1,2,3,4

[image: I WANT IT TO LOOK LIKE THIS IN PERFECT ORDER BY ID 1,2,3,4]

The reason why I want do this because I want my questions in my container to appear in order by ID, here my codes, any thoughts how i do achieve that?

```
class QuestionContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      questions: [],
    };
    this.SubmitQuestion = this.SubmitQuestion.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`${env.url}/api/v1/en/questions?limit=100`).then((res) => {
      const qes = res.data.questions.map((a) => ({
        questionId: a.question_no,
        question: a.question,
      }));
      this.setState({ questions: qes });
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('Question fetch error ', err);
      this.setState({
        questions: [{
          questionId: 1,
          question: 'All',
        }],
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm struggling to follow the question.  Could you post a same table and what you want the result of the query to look like; a before/after view.

Comment: @Mike Sure I have updated my questions with images, apologies for my bad english

Comment: But id 3 is missing...

Comment: @Andronicus the list goes on to hundreds, and number 3 is and other numbers are mixed in order.

Comment: Well my autocomplete kicked in. That should have said "sample" not "same" :)

Comment: Rows in a relational database do not have any implied order. The **only** (really: the only) way to get a sorted result is to an an ORDER BY to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things:

1. when tuples are retrieved it is not guaranteed that they will be sorted in a consistent manner.  They are compiled into a set for speed, which may be a random order.  The way to enforce a sort order is to use the `ORDER BY` clause.  Without it, there is no guarantee
2. I'd advise against using the `id` (primary key) as the ordered column.  If order is important, I'd either add an `order` column to the table, or what I prefer is to have a timestamp field.  In your case, though, it looks like `question_no` has a semantic order, so I might have used that over `id`.
3. your example looks like it's using JavaScript React; you can get the order from the database, or you can update the order in your presentation logic.  Below I've used `.sort((a,b)=>a.questionId - b.questionId)`, which is a quick example:

   ```
   const qes = res.data.questions.map((a) => ({
     questionId: a.question_no,
     question: a.question,
   })).sort((a,b)=>a.questionId - b.questionId);
   ```
4. If you wanted to try and retrieve it without the sort, I think you can pass an argument to the axios API.  So this line:

   ```
   axios.get(`${env.url}/api/v1/en/questions?limit=100`)
   ```

   Would be changed to:

   ```
   axios.get(`${env.url}/api/v1/en/questions?orderBy=\"question_no\"&limit=100`)
   ```

Comment: `res.data.questions.map((a) => ({
  questionId: a.question_no,
  question: a.question,
})).sort((a,b)=>a.question_no-b.question_no);`

Comment: @Ben it looks like you just copied what I put (or I can't see the difference), but it did help me see that he renamed `question_no` to `questionId`.  Answer updated

Comment: Thank you really appreciate it, i think im just gonna go with getting the order from here however im still confused how im gonna do it. I managed to do 
But im struggling with how to sort it by question_no or id just like u did and its what exactly i need to do.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're asking.  You might be able to forego `sort()` altogether, with the update to the axios call, which should be calling `ORDER BY` in the database query.  That said, the `a` and `b` are just variables that point to two elements of an array (current and next values) in order to compare.  It evaluates that one is greater than the other and changes the order of the elements based on whether the return value is positive, negative, or zero.

Comment: it's all good, i thought i was doing something wrong but with the advice you gave finally made it in order. You saved so much of my headache. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You *always* have to add `ORDER BY` if you want the result to be in a certain order.

Tables have a physical order, but in PostgreSQL that changes whenever you modify data, and even if you don't modify data you are not guaranteed to get the results in a certain order.

Comment: Thanks you The reason why I do this because I want the questions apeared in my question container to be in order by ID.., any thought how I am going to implement that?

I updated my question with the codes..

Comment: Simply add an `ORDER BY` to the SQL statement. I don't know what you have to do with your ORM (that you didn't tag) to get that.